# in java,how to get the string(date)from log message

Tags: java, string

i want to get the date from the log message.ie,in log message, i am having different type of date formats.

for ex,

```
Sample1.txt --- Jun 17 09:28:53 Sample sentences for this example
Sample2.txt --- 17 Jun 2011 09:28:53 Sample sentences for this example
```

from this messages,i need to get `"date"(17 Jun 2011 09:28:53 or Jun 17 09:28:53)`.Is there any easiest and efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can your the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("17 Jun 2011 09:28:53");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` and try all possible formats (catching `ParseException`)

So make a `List<SimpleDateFormat>`, initiate it (mind concurrency issues, it's not thread-safe), and inside the loop catch `ParseException`

The exact date format strings should be found in your logger configuration (or you can infer them from the messages)