# How can I extract list a time from string?

Tags: java

I want to extract the list of time from this string

> **20:00-24:00、17:00-21:00、6:30-9:00 など、夜中心に募集！6:30-24:00の間で 1日2時間～ＯＫ！夏休みの短期も可**

Comment: See Pattern class in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in java,how to get the string(date)from log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387883/in-java-how-to-get-the-stringdatefrom-log-message)

Comment: Try this regex: `([0-2]?\d:[0-5]\d)-([0-2]?\d:[0-5]\d)` ([test online](https://regex101.com/r/v26IMs/2))

Answer (score 0):

You can make use the following regex:

```
((?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)-((?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)
```

Which matches on a range. E.g: `15:56-23:10`.

This can then be used in conjunction with the `Pattern` class from `java.util.regex`, to find out every range in the input string:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:[01]?\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d)-((?:[01]?\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()){
    String from = matcher.group(1);
    String to = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `([0-2]?\d:[0-5]\d)-([0-2]?\d:[0-5]\d)`

Online test: [Link](https://regex101.com/r/v26IMs/2)

Java implementation:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([0-2]?\\d:[0-5]\\d)-([0-2]?\\d:[0-5]\\d)";
final String string = "20:00-24:00、17:00-21:00、6:30-9:00 など、夜中心に募集！6:30-24:00の間で 1日2時間～ＯＫ！夏休みの短期も可";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```